# Calculate Max Frequency for every Sequence_ID in full Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe Like:

```
Time        Frq_1   Seq_1       Frq_2   Seq_2       Frq_3   Seq_3
12:43:04    0.00    30668.00    0.00    30670.00    4620.00 30671.00
12:46:05    0.00    30699.00    0.00    30699.00    3280.00 30700.00
12:46:17    4200.00 30700.00    0.00    30704.00    0.00    30704.00
12:46:18    3060.00 30700.00    4200.00 30700.00    0.00    30700.00
12:46:18    3060.00 30700.00    4200.00 30700.00    0.00    30700.00
12:46:19    3060.00 30700.00    4220.00 30700.00    0.00    30700.00
12:46:20    3060.00 30700.00    4240.00 30700.00    0.00    30700.00
12:46:37    0.00    30698.00    0.00    30699.00    3060.00 30700.00
12:46:38    0.00    30699.00    3060.00 30700.00    4600.00 30700.00
12:47:19    0.00    30668.00    0.00    30669.00    0.00    30669.00
12:47:20    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30668.00
12:47:20    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30668.00
12:47:21    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30667.00    0.00    30668.00
12:47:21    0.00    30665.00    0.00    30665.00    0.00    30665.00
12:47:22    0.00    30665.00    0.00    30665.00    0.00    30665.00
12:48:35    0.00    30688.00    0.00    30690.00    3020.00 30690.00
12:49:29    4160.00 30690.00    0.00    30691.00    0.00    30693.00
```

I want check the total dataframe and find the result with below condition:

> 1. Sequence_ID for which Frequency is not null  Sequence_ID for which
> 2. Frequency is Max (in case of multiple Sequence_ID with non zero Frequency)

I want my result as below:

```
Time         Sequence_ID   Frequency
12:43:04     4620          30671 
12:49:29     4160          30690 
12:46:38     4600          30700
```

> Time = correspond to row of (Sequence_ID & Frequency)

Comment: why there is no `4200.00 30700.00` ?

Comment: its there Sir, at 12:46:38 last set of (Frq_3   Seq_3)

Comment: I see that from *Frq_1 / Seq_1* you selected *12:49:29  4160.00  30690*.
Note that in this pair of columns it is **not** the max frequency.
What is the reason of this selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need max value of `Frq` per groups first reshape by [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), filter out `0` values by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                     stubnames=['Frq','Seq'],
                     i=['Time','index'],
                     j='group',
                     sep='_')
       .reset_index(level=[0,2])
       .query("Frq != 0")
       .sort_values(['group','Frq'], ascending=[True, False])

       )
```

---

```
print (df)
           Time  group     Frq      Seq
index                                  
2      12:46:17      1  4200.0  30700.0
16     12:49:29      1  4160.0  30690.0
3      12:46:18      1  3060.0  30700.0
4      12:46:18      1  3060.0  30700.0
5      12:46:19      1  3060.0  30700.0
6      12:46:20      1  3060.0  30700.0
6      12:46:20      2  4240.0  30700.0
5      12:46:19      2  4220.0  30700.0
3      12:46:18      2  4200.0  30700.0
4      12:46:18      2  4200.0  30700.0
8      12:46:38      2  3060.0  30700.0
0      12:43:04      3  4620.0  30671.0
8      12:46:38      3  4600.0  30700.0
1      12:46:05      3  3280.0  30700.0
7      12:46:37      3  3060.0  30700.0
15     12:48:35      3  3020.0  30690.0
```

Last for max value per groups is used [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('group')
print (df1)
           Time  group     Frq      Seq
index                                  
2      12:46:17      1  4200.0  30700.0
6      12:46:20      2  4240.0  30700.0
0      12:43:04      3  4620.0  30671.0
```